# Python Django vs ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, python, asp.net-mvc, django

I am fairly new at web development scene, and I was wondering if you can help me break up the pros and cons of using python django vs asp.net mvc besides the maturity level of its framework.

I have intermediate experience with Java. As of right now, I am leaning towards Python, but I just wanted to make sure, I am making the right choice. I find myself limited with books available on asp.net web developments. I am aware that there is the storefront example on the official asp.net site. However, that tutorial was a little hard for me to follow. I've done a research around and was hoping python could be my next available choice. There are more tutorials available online for Python anyways.

What do you think?

Comment: Python and django are opensource, but that only matters if you care about reading the source. Sometimes I found it handy to  be able to read the code.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is also open source. http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/23011#

Answer (score 4):

It always make sens to do some research regarding technologies trends and professionals demand, you can do this by using Google tools, such as [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/?q=django%20python,ruby%20on%20rails,%20asp.net%20mvc&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=1)
[image]

It will save you time and help you to choose right direction. See more details about [technology research here](http://podlipensky.com/2012/06/choosing-web-framework-asp-net-mvc-vs-django-python-vs-ruby-on-rails/). Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET MVC is pretty cool if you already know C# and/or ASP... but if you're starting from scratch, Django is (IMO) a better bet.  You probably have more hosting options for Django, for one thing.

Comment: ++ for the hosting comment.

It's hard to find a discount host with even mediocre Windows shared hosting. I've worked with a few, and customer support is typically clueless about how to administrate a Windows machine. The only host in this category I would recommend is Arvixe, though admittedly I have limited experience with them.

Comment: Which host do you use/recommend for django?

Comment: You don't need Windows hosting to run an ASP.NET MVC site - it will run on Linux with Mono.